# How to hide URL for downloadable product in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, urls

I am using Wordpress 4.9.8 and WooCommerce 3.4.6 and Feed Them Gallery PRemium for bulk upload to sell photos.
My problem is when a customer buy a photos, it works fine, but on the order-re ceived page the name showed for the url of the photo, is somethign like

> https://instantmax.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/tennis03.jpg

which is just impossible!
Any customer can then found any photo.
How can I hide that url?
[image]
Any help much appreciate.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who knows the absolute path of a file can find it.
There are several possibilities, two simple ideas to set up:

- Generate a random name for each file
- Generate a temporary link for each download

In both cases, I guess a plugin already exists.

Comment: Thanks ~@Thomazzi.
I am already using Feed Them Gallery and I fear to use an additional plugin, with FT Gallery, Woocommerce and my theme, which is already a problem...